# CakePHP - a code sample seems strange to me, what am i missing?

Tags: php, cakephp

Attached code [taken from cakephp bakery,](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/aranworld/2008/01/14/using-equalto-validation-to-compare-two-form-fields) where someone uploaded a sample about custom validation rules.

```
class Contact extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Contact';
    var $validate = array(
        'email' => array(
            'identicalFieldValues' => array(
                 'rule'    => array('identicalFieldValues', 'confirm_email' ),
                 'message' => 'Please re-enter your password twice so that the values match'
                )
            )
        );


    function identicalFieldValues( $field=array(), $compare_field=null ) 
    {
        foreach( $field as $key => $value ){
            $v1 = $value;
            $v2 = $this->data[$this->name][ $compare_field ];                 
            if($v1 !== $v2) {
                return FALSE;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
    }

}
```

In the code, the guy used a foreach to access an array member which he had its name already!
As far as I understand - it's a waste of resources and a bad(even strange) practice.

One more thing about the code:
I don't understand the usage of the `continue` there. it's a single field array, isn't it? the comparison should happen once and the loop will be over.
Please enlighten me.

Comment: What do you mean by "the guy used a foreach to access an array member which he had its name already"

Comment: The first parameter is always an array on one key and its value, the second parameter comes from the call to that function, in a block named as the key... 
So, all you need is to send the key and no need to iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the code, the guy used a foreach to access an array member which he had its name already! As far as I understand - it's a waste of resources and a bad(even strange) practice.
>
> The first parameter is always an array on one key and its value, the second parameter comes from the call to that function, in a block named as the key... So, all you need is to send the key and no need to iterate

The code uses `foreach` to iterate through `$field`, which is an array of one key value pair. It all starts when the validation routine invokes `identicalFieldValues`, passing it two values - `$field`, which would be an array that looks like:

```
array ( 
    [email] => 'user entered value 1'
)
```

The second parameter `$compare_field` would be set to the string `confirm_email`.

In this particular case, it doesn't look like it makes a lot of sense to use `foreach` since your array only has one key-value pair. But you must write code this way because CakePHP **will** pass an array to the method.

I believe the reason why CakePHP does this is because an array is the only way to pass both the field name and its value. While in this case the field name (email) is irrelevant, you might need in other cases.

What you are seeing here is one of the caveats of using frameworks. Most of the time, they simplify your code. But sometimes you have to write code that you wouldn't write normally just so the framework is happy.

---

> One more thing about the code: I don't understand the usage of the continue there. it's a single field array, isn't it? the comparison should happen once and the loop will be over. Please enlighten me.

Indeed. And since there are no statements in the foreach loop following `continue`, the whole `else` block could also be omitted.

A simplified version of this would be:

```
function identicalFieldValues($field=array(), $compare_field=null) 
{
    foreach ($field as $field) {

        $compare = $this->data[$this->name][$compare_field];                 
        if ($field !== $compare) {
            return FALSE;
        } 
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

And I agree with you, the loop only goes through one iteration <s>when validating the `email` field.</s> regardless of the field. You still need the `foreach` because you are getting an array though.

Comment: Well, first: thanks. as to the second part - since the array is ALWAYS a single record array, the continue will never be used.
My assumption is that the code came from some other, more generic, function, and was adapted to this use, while keeping the original structure...

Comment: Got it, but one thing isn't clear - since the array will ALWAYS hold only one record! the framework documentation specifies it. 
I guess that it's a practice to use more generic code. thanks for walking through it .. i'm less confused now

Comment: @yossi Thanks... I updated my answer again in light of the new information.

Comment: even less code: http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/07/19/extended-core-validation-rules/ (validateIdentical)